# Good solution for adding tags into a mixed-content textarea field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

Been trying to find a good solution for this, but I haven't discovered anything. I've found plenty of plugins that turn an input into a taggable text entry field, but nearly all of them are for adding "only" tags. The closest I've found is this: http://daniel-zahariev.github.com/jquery-textntags/

The problem with that, though, is editing. If you type 10 sentences and put a tag in each one, then click back up to, say, the 5th sentence and decide you want to add another tag, the styling gets all out of whack for several of the existing tags... Ultimately I would love to write a patch for this, but I need something quick and easy to implement.

What I ultimately need to end up with is a plugin that allows me to edit paragraphs of text, adding and deleting tags wherever in that text that our editors want without breaking the existing tags... make sense? Thoughts?

Comment: Very sensible question. I'm assuming your use case looks a lot like the input-box on Facebook or Google+. I have some experience with implementing something similar and I have to admit it's not easy. `contentEditable` is really buggy on all browsers (including the latest version of Chrome). I have found a plugin that helps make it easier to manipulate the caret position and the selection: rangy (you can find it on code.google.com).

Comment: I second Frits. contentEditable + Rangy. But it's far from quick and easy. You will possibly have some problems with undo and redo. Internet Explorer, for example, clears undo stack when you add/remove elements or change innerHTML. You can try to work around this by document.ExecCommand('insertHTML'). Also you'll possibly need to clean up HTML on paste.